# Swift ひとつ前の作業行程にもどる

Tags: swift

Swift ひとつ前の作業行程の画面にもどる機能 をつけるにはどうしたらいいですか？

Answer (score 0, accepted):

クラス`UndoManager`を利用します。

[Apple Developer - class UndoManager](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/undomanager)
[日本語の`UndoManager`の解説で、見つけたもののひとつ](https://sussan-po.com/2020/03/21/how-to-use-undomanager/)

Comment: ありがとうございます